# how to implement custom php function on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, jsonp

I was searched a lot in stackoverflow and google and I found some possible manuals but any of these was working for me, so I come here to search an solution, also this could help to other to see how to implement custom functions on wordpress..

I have a webpage where in the top body of it I call using json with auth the last twitter of my account and publish in the website, so for implement that in wordpress makes some error 403 forbidden...

so in the index.php top body in the scripts that call the functions is...

```
<div><p><?php echo webstrategic_processString($twitter); ?></p></div>
```

and the file where is the function (functios.php in same folder) is this:

```
/* start function twitter texts twitter api v1.1*/
require_once("./twitteroauth.php"); //Path to twitteroauth library

$twitteruser = "someuser";
$notweets = 1;
$consumerkey = "8kZ6edmqkvCuGg";
$consumersecret = "uG0Qpd4BiyfUHYn250xCkFU";
$accesstoken = "37248546-DNmlMoDoLBmapEGydhwNFRiq5";
$accesstokensecret = "QolC4RhQHYErAxsBQlgGzBfu3dXM0";

function getConnectionWithAccessToken($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret) {
  $connection = new TwitterOAuth($cons_key, $cons_secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
  return $connection;
}

$connection = getConnectionWithAccessToken($consumerkey, $consumersecret, $accesstoken, $accesstokensecret);
$tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);
$twitter = json_encode($tweets[0]->text); 
$twitter = substr($twitter, 1, -1);

function processString($twitter) {
    return preg_replace(array('/https?:\/\/[\w\-\.!~?&+\*\'"(),\/]+/', '#@([\\d\\w]+)#', '/#([\\d\\w]+)/'), array('<a href="$0" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">$0</a>', '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">$0</a>','<a href="http://twitter.com/search?q=%23$1&amp;src=hash" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">$0</a>'), $twitter);
}
$twitter = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9abcdef]{4})/", "&#x$1;", $tweets[0]->text); // this line changes from unicode to utf-8
```

The question is, how to apply this than I have in functions.php to wordpress functions to make able to work with my wordpress theme and calle the function in wp header theme and work? using the next line code:

```
<div><p><?php echo webstrategic_processString($twitter); ?></p></div>
```

thanks! ='(

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your custom function to run when the template is rendering the header, inside your theme's `functions.php`

```
add_action('wp_head', 'echo_twitter');

function echo_twitter() {
   global $twitter;
   // assuming your $twitter variable is available as a global
   echo '<div><p>'.webstrategic_processString($twitter).'</p></div>';
}
```

[See here for more info on using Wordpress hooks and using them in themes.](http://www.sitepoint.com/customizing-wordpress-themes-with-action-hooks/)

Comment: This will echo the desired HTML inside the `<head>` element, which is invalid markup. Instead, add a custom action after the opening `<body>` tag like this: `<?php do_action('after_body'); ?>`
Then, change the line `add_action('wp_head', 'echo_twitter');` to `add_action('after_body', 'echo_twitter');`

Comment: I try to implement in that form but i want to call the function from the template file, to say where exactly i want to make echo in the html... (in that form it prints at the top of the site!. also the website is makeing some error 403 forbidden and i don't know why is that error ! :S
this is the link: [diseño web](http://www.clonick.com/blog/)